# Examples of using Avro in ruby for intercommunication for microservices

Tags: ruby, avro, microservices

I'm doing a little research into intra microservice communication and I stumbled onto [this web-blog](http://blog.salsify.com/engineering/adventures-in-avro) and found it interesting. The problem however is I can't seem to find any examples of using avro for communication so could some one link some resources on this, specifically aimed at ruby?

Or have I completely misunderstood it's purpose and it's not meant for use in micro-services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find this blog:

https://www.igvita.com/2010/02/16/data-serialization-rpc-with-avro-ruby/

which linked to the following samples:

## client(send)

https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/trunk/lang/ruby/test/sample_ipc_client.rb

## server(receive)

https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/trunk/lang/ruby/test/sample_ipc_server.rb